# Why VirtualHost not working?

Tags: apache

This may be stupid query. My VirtualHost is not working, wonder why?

I have myvhost.conf in /etc/apache2/site-enabled. It's looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName dev.mydomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I am on Ubuntu: 14.10, Apache: 2.4.10. I have other vhost file 000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf. The default (both http and https) is working.

**Edit**: When I browse dev.mydomain.com, I get Apache default page iie. "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there an error in log files ? or maybe syntax ? what's happening if you launch apache with `-t` option ?

Comment: There is no error - I get default page "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" when I do dev.mydomain.com

Comment: Is dev.mydomain.com the system hostname?

Answer (score 0):

Try that and remove your default vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                                                       
  ServerName  dev.mydomain.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
  <Directory /var/www/html/test>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 LogLevel warn

 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```